# Sprout Form Not Saving Entries

Tags: entries, form, plugin-sproutforms

We have a Sprout Forms form being used for gated content access. The form appears to work correctly but none of the entries are appearing in the database/CMS.

Here is an example URL with the form: http://thisisbeyond.co.uk/blog/feel-good-brands-report-2015/

Below is a CMS screenshot of the form settings.[image]

Below is the template code we are using to generate the form:

```
{% if craft.request.getParam('message') == 'success' %}

<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Thank you for your message, we'll get back to you as soon as possible.</div>

{% else %}

{% macro errorList(errors) %}
{% if errors %}
{% for error in errors %}
<span class="label label-alert">{{ error }}</span>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{% from _self import errorList %}

<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
{{ getCsrfInput() }}
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="sproutForms/entries/saveEntry">
<input type="hidden" name="handle" value="gatedForm">
{% set gated = entry.gatedDocument.first() %}
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ gated.url }}">

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="fields-fullName">Full Name *</label>
    <input type="text" name="fields[fullName]" id="fields-fullName" class="form-control" value="{% if gatedForm.fullName is defined %}{{ gatedForm.fullName }}{% endif %}" required/>
    {% if gatedForm is defined %}{{ errorList(gatedForm.getErrors('fullName')) }}{% endif %}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="fields-companyName">Company Name *</label>
    <input type="text" name="fields[companyName]" id="fields-companyName" class="form-control" value="{% if gatedForm.companyName is defined %}{{ gatedForm.companyName }}{% endif %}" required/>
    {% if gatedForm is defined %}{{ errorList(gatedForm.getErrors('companyName')) }}{% endif %}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="fields-email">Email *</label>
    <input type="text" name="fields[email]" id="fields-email" class="form-control" value="{% if gatedForm.email is defined %}{{ gatedForm.email }}{% endif %}" required/>
    {% if gatedForm is defined %}{{ errorList(gatedForm.getErrors('email')) }}{% endif %}
</div>

<p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</p>

</form>

{% endif %}
```

UPDATE: re-installing the Sprout Invisible Captcha plugin and including the following line before the closing  tag got it working:

```
{{ craft.sproutInvisibleCaptcha.protect() }}
```

Comment: Hi Steve, is it possible you have Invisible Captcha or another spam prevention plugin silently blocking your form submissions?

Comment: Hi Ben, That may be a possibility. I'll take a look into that, thanks

Comment: Hi Ben, that helped me to get to the bottom of it. I needed to re-install the Sprout Invisible Captcha plugin and add a line to the template to include it. I'll update the question with the code snippet

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, @SteveRowland. Can you add that as an official answer?

Answer (score 4):

Re-installing the Sprout Invisible Captcha plugin and including the following line before the closing tag got it working:

```
{{ craft.sproutInvisibleCaptcha.protect() }}
```